# Declaring Datatype as Form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I want to declare a parameter as `Form` at the below:

```
void Func(Form frm)
{
    frm emp = new frm();
}
```

but I got an error I can't delcare like that. Any suggestion ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`frm` is a variable not a type

```
void Func(Form frm)
{
    Form emp = frm;
}
```

Comment: Why I can't think about this algorithm ?? :D

Answer (score 2):

You are using [variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wew5ytx4(v=vs.90).aspx) ([method parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8f1hz171.aspx)) that is the instance of object as a type name.

You should not call [`new`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fa0ab757.aspx) operator because you are already have created instance.

> New operator used to create objects and invoke [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6sa6h87.aspx).

Then you just need to use [the assignment operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbkb459w.aspx) or use variable as is:

```
void Func(Form frm)
{
    frm.Show();
    //Form emp = frm;
}
```